# how can I delete apps that aren't installed in dash?

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

I installed `Navicat` with `Wine` then I uninstall it and delete the folder `.wine` in `home` directory but when I search `Navicat` in the dash always appears, I already tried to restart my laptop, log out and log in as well, but no matter what I do

[image]

Comment: When you click on them do they launch, if not then you need to remove the `.desktop` files from `~/.local/share/applications`, and or `/usr/share/applications`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look in these locations:

```
~/.local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications
```

for the `.desktop` files. Remove them and those entries in `dash` should disappear. If your files in `/usr/share/applications` are much which I believe they are then using these command **after changing into** that folder to find the files of interest:

```
grep -Rio navicat .
grep -Rio wine .
```

Note: You can change the search name(s) for grep accordingly to find these files, the files in `~/.local/share` should be fewer and easier to search without the grep command.